# How do I determine the "hand" of the door?

Tags: interior, product-recommendation, doors, front-door

*I apologize in advance if this post is confusing. Let me know if additional clarification is needed. =)*

I'm planning to install a new front door and am confused on what the appropriate "hand" orientation of the door would be.  The [schlage handleset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001NEK976) I'm planning to get comes in right-handed and left-handed lever models.

Here's a picture of the old/original door:

[image]

On the Amazon page, there's also a helpful diagram:

[image]

Based on this, I would conclude that I have a left-handed door.

But here's what confuses me: on the same amazon page, there's another diagram: 
[image]

This doesn't make sense to me.  The second diagram makes it appear that the "left handed" lever will stick out to the left.  If that's the case, I would think that I would want to purchase the "right-handed" door lever.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handle pictures in the second diagram is very misleading.  Since the outside handle is obvious, the second pic should be the inside picture, but thet are labeled wrong for this handle it appears.  My guess is that the second pic is meant for any interior door, and for exterior doors with special exterior handles, it is wrong.

You are right, your door is left handed.  I think you would be safe ordering the LH handles.  If you are still nervous, I would take a trip to home depot or lowes to look at similar handles and confirm that LH is the way to go.

[Here is the link](http://consumer.schlage.com/Products/Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?ModelNumber=FE285%20CAM%20619%20ACC) to the actual product on the Schlage website.  Unfortunately, I dont see much to help even in the documentation.  I do see that you can flip the handle if desired, but then the curvature would be up and not down on the handle.

Also FYI, most interior door handes are reversible.  But in your case, since it is an exterior handle, it does matter.

Answer (score 2):

Simple time tested method.  Stand on the hinge side of the door with your back to the door. If the hinges are on the left, it is a left hand out swing, on the right, right hand out swing. Works every time. lol

Comment: If that's the case, then I would likely want a right-handed door handle.  Because on the hinge side, the hinges are on the right and the old door knob is on the left.  This would seem to conflict with the first diagram. Mike = confused.

Comment: using this method you would also have to state if you were standing on the outside or inside.

Comment: if you are standing on the pin hinged side of any door, you are also standing on the out swing side of that door regardless if you are indoors or outdoors.

Comment: BTW, your pic shows a left hand swing door.

Answer (score 1):

Stand so the door opens towards you (i.e. on the hinge side)
  Grab the knob/handle.  Which hand did you use?  That's the hand of the door.

Quick and dirty MS Paint --[image: Hand of Door]

Comment: You are correct! +1. Forget outside and inside. If you are on the hinged side of the door, it will swing toward you. Handle on the left is left-handed. On the right is right-handed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and the assumption in each of these is that the door is opening to the inside.  To simplify, look where you want the hinges to be LH or RH, this along with the need to communicate Open inwards or Open outwards will make it easier to view and express the outcome.

Comment: This is very confusing. Care to [edit] it to clarify what you mean? Door "hand" is fairly standardized and there's really no need that I'm aware of to indicate "open in" or "open out". If you could edit in a drawing that shows how this makes a difference, I'm sure that would help.